# How to feed the output of a finetuned bert model as inpunt to another finetuned bert model?

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I finetuned two separate bert model (bert-base-uncased) on sentiment analysis and pos tagging tasks. Now, I want to feed the output of the pos tagger (batch, seqlength, hiddensize) as input to the sentiment model.The original bert-base-uncased model is in 'bertModel/' folder which contains 'model.bin' and 'config.json'. Here is my code:

```
class DeepSequentialModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, sentiment_model_file, postag_model_file, device):
    super(DeepSequentialModel, self).__init__()

    self.sentiment_model = SentimentModel().to(device)
    self.sentiment_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(sentiment_model_file, map_location=device))
    self.postag_model = PosTagModel().to(device)
    self.postag_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(postag_model_file, map_location=device))

    self.classificationLayer = nn.Linear(768, 1)

def forward(self, seq, attn_masks):
    postag_context = self.postag_model(seq, attn_masks)
    sent_context = self.sentiment_model(postag_context, attn_masks)
    logits = self.classificationLayer(sent_context)
    return logits

class PosTagModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,):
    super(PosTagModel, self).__init__()
    self.bert_layer = BertModel.from_pretrained('bertModel/')
    self.classificationLayer = nn.Linear(768, 43)

def forward(self, seq, attn_masks):
    cont_reps, _ = self.bert_layer(seq, attention_mask=attn_masks)
    return cont_reps

class SentimentModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,):
    super(SentimentModel, self).__init__()
    self.bert_layer = BertModel.from_pretrained('bertModel/')
    self.cls_layer = nn.Linear(768, 1)

def forward(self, input, attn_masks):
    cont_reps, _ = self.bert_layer(encoder_hidden_states=input, encoder_attention_mask=attn_masks)
    cls_rep = cont_reps[:, 0]
    return cls_rep
```

But I get the below error. I appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks!

```
    cont_reps, _ = self.bert_layer(encoder_hidden_states=input, encoder_attention_mask=attn_masks)
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder_hidden_states'
```

Comment: Which version of `transformers` are you using?

Comment: @dennlinger
transformers 2.1.1

Comment: Then it is time to update your transformers version. The [documentation for 2.1.1](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v2.1.1/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L159) clearly lists a very outdated version of the forward pass, so this is the reason why you cannot access the (at that point non-existent) argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formulate this as an answer, too, and keep it properly visible for future visitors, the `forward()` call of transformers [does not support these arguments in version 2.1.1](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v2.1.1/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L201), or any earlier version, for that matter. note that the link in my comment is in fact pointing to a different forward function, but otherwise the point still holds.

Passing `encoder_hidden_states` to `forward()` was [first possible in version 2.2.0](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v2.2.0/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L210).